# On the universal property of Tensor Product

Tags: proof-explanation, tensor-products, universal-property

I was readying the construction of the Tensor Product that was made on the book **Introduction to Smooth Manifolds**, from John M. Lee. In the **proposition 12.7** he proved that his construction satisfied the universal property of the Tensor Product. His proof follows:

[image]

where $\mathfrak{F}(V\times W)$ denotes the free vector space over $V\times W$, and $\mathcal{R}$ is the subspace spanned by the vector of the form
$$
\begin{array}{c}
(v + v',w) - (v,w) - (v',w)\\
(v, w + w') - (v,w) - (v,w')\\
(\lambda v,w) - \lambda(v,w)\\
(v,\lambda w) - \lambda(v,w)\\
\end{array}
$$
and $\Pi$ is the natural projection that sends each element of $\mathfrak{F}(V\times W)$ on it's equivalence class in $\mathfrak{F}(V\times W)/\mathcal{R}$.

My doubt about his proof is the step: $\mathcal{R}\text{ contained in }ker(\overline{A}) \Rightarrow \overline{A}\text{ descends to a linear map $\widetilde{A}$ such that} \widetilde{A}\circ\Pi = \overline{A}$. Where did he get this implication from? and why $\widetilde{A}$ is a linear map, exactly?

I'm sorry if it's too much text and sorry about the image, but I'm really confused about this step.

Comment: It's the universal property of the quotient space. The proof is essentially just composing the universal properties of the free and quotient spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doubt is a well know theorem in linear algebra. You can find it in any linear algebra text worth reading or for example [here](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/qtvector.pdf) on the second page.

The basic idea is to define $\tilde{A} ([x]) = \overline{A} (x)$, where $[x] = \Pi (x)$ is the equivalence class of $x \in \mathfrak{F}(V \times W)$. This map ($\tilde{A}$) is well defined, because $\mathcal{R} \subset \ker \overline{A}$ and linear, because $\overline{A}$ is.